# Spring REST Doc unamed request parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-restdocs

I am writing the documentation of my rest service using the [Spring REST Docs library](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/#documenting-your-api-request-parameters).

A problem I have is that I accept a POST request with a JSON structure as an input that does not have any name.

The request looks something like this :

```
POST /images?limit=3&offset=12 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Length: 289

{"acquisitionWindow":0,"platformName":"myPlatform","requireImageFile":false,"requireImageFileOrQuicklook":false,"strictPolygon":false,"showInternal":false,"imageNames":["%"],"startTimeOfYear":0,"stopTimeOfYear":0,"resolutionLowerBound":0.0,"resolutionUpperBound":0.0,"reducedResolution":0}
```

I would like to document the input structure, but have found no way to do it so far.

The documentation describes something like this :

```
this.mockMvc.perform(get("/users?page=2&per_page=100")) 
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andDo(document("users", requestParameters( 
            parameterWithName("page").description("The page to retrieve"), 
            parameterWithName("per_page").description("Entries per page") 
    )));
```

But my parameter has no name.

What I have tried to far :

```
requestParameters(
    // TODO: Insert ImageSearch here
    parameterWithName("{}").description("ImageSearch Structure "))
```

I have also tried with an empty name **("")**, and the array notation **("[]")**. No luck so far.

Is it possible to document unamed parameters, or should I wrap it in another structure?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood what the unnamed parameter is. Is it the JSON in the body of the POST request?

Comment: Yes! The whole json object is called an ImageSearch on the back-end side. This object contains a lot of search parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `requestFields` on `org.springframework.restdocs.payload.PayloadDocumentation` to document the JSON payload that's sent in the request. For example:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(get("/users?page=2&per_page=100")) 
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andDo(document("users", requestFields( 
            fieldWithPath("acquisitionWindow").description("…"), 
            fieldWithPath("platformName").description("…"))));
```

See the [Request and response payloads section of the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/#documenting-your-api-request-response-payloads) for some further details.

Comment: Alright so you confirm what I had in mind. If I prefer to document those items as a separate object in my documentation, I have to manually (statically) indicate the top level JSON object as an ImageSearch. Thanks